# Group by two columns expecting all the values, selected from other table, in second column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by

I have two table.

### **Table1**

```
+----------+
| column1  |
+----------+
| data1    |
+----------+
| data2    |
+----------+
| data3    |
+----------+
| data4    |
+----------+
| data5    |
+----------+
```

### **Table2**

```
+--------------------------------+
| column1 | column2    | COLUMN3 |
+--------------------------------+
| 1       | data1      | 1       |
+--------------------------------+
| 1       | data2      | 2       |
+--------------------------------+
| 1       | data2      | 3       |
+--------------------------------+
| 1       | data4      | 4       |
+--------------------------------+
| 2       | data1      | 5       |
+--------------------------------+
| 2       | data5      | 6       |
+--------------------------------+
```

### **Query**

```
SELECT T2.COLUMN1, T2.COLUMN2, SUM(T2.COLUMN3) 
FROM Table1 T1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 
ON T1.COLUMN1 = T2.COLUMN2 
GROUP BY T2.COLUMN1, T2.COLUMN2 
ORDER BY T2.COLUMN1
```

The result which I get is

### **Result**

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 1       | data1   | 1       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 1       | data2   | 5       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 1       | data4   | 4       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 2       | data1   | 5       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 2       | data5   | 6       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

But I don't want this result. The expected result is as follows.

### **Expected Result**

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 1       | data1   | 1       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 1       | data2   | 5       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 1       | data3   | 0       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 1       | data4   | 4       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 1       | data5   | 0       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 2       | data1   | 5       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 2       | data2   | 0       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 2       | data3   | 0       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 2       | data4   | 0       |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 2       | data5   | 6       |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting @Arun Palanisamy

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a [*partitioned outer join*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_10002.htm#i2196190) introduced in Oracle 10 to handle the case when the driving table in `oter join` has gaps.

This feature enables you to **avoid the usage of** `CROSS JOIN` *as proposed in other answer*.

This query delivers the detail data by *filling the gaps in the outer join*

```
select  T2.COLUMN1, T1.COLUMN1 COLUMN2, nvl(T2.COLUMN3,0) COLUMN3
from Table1 T1 
left outer join Table2 T2 partition by (T2.column1)
on T1.COLUMN1 = T2.COLUMN2
order by 1,2;

   COLUMN1 COLUMN2                                         COLUMN3
---------- -------------------------------------------- ----------
         1 data1                                                 1 
         1 data2                                                 2 
         1 data2                                                 3 
         1 data3                                                 0 
         1 data4                                                 4 
         1 data5                                                 0 
         2 data1                                                 5 
         2 data2                                                 0 
         2 data3                                                 0 
         2 data4                                                 0 
         2 data5                                                 6
```

Simple add the `group by` to get the expected result.

```
select  T2.COLUMN1, T1.COLUMN1 COLUMN2, sum(nvl(T2.COLUMN3,0)) COLUMN3
from Table1 T1 
left outer join Table2 T2 partition by (T2.column1)
on T1.COLUMN1 = T2.COLUMN2
group by T2.COLUMN1, T1.COLUMN1
order by 1,2;

   COLUMN1 COLUMN2                                         COLUMN3
---------- -------------------------------------------- ----------
         1 data1                                                 1 
         1 data2                                                 5 
         1 data3                                                 0 
         1 data4                                                 4 
         1 data5                                                 0 
         2 data1                                                 5 
         2 data2                                                 0 
         2 data3                                                 0 
         2 data4                                                 0 
         2 data5                                                 6
```

Answer (score 2):

We can handle this requirement using a calendar table:

```
SELECT
    t2.column1,
    t1.column1,
    s.column3
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM Table2) t2
LEFT JOIN Table2 s
    ON t1.column1 = s.column2 AND
       t2.column1 = s.column1
ORDER BY
    t2.column1,
    t1.column1;
```

The subquery aliased as `t2` above serves as a proxy for a table which contains all possible `column2` values from `Table2`.